# Players not appearing after second level generation

Tags: python

Second levels is showing up correctly but the player turtle(blue square) and player2 turtle(red square) are not appearing, everything else appears as needed. The players should appear where I have marked them in the level define as P and L.

Here's my code https://github.com/JpJanse/Recycling-Game/blob/main/main.py

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: I suggest to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: I think `wn.clear()` removes all objects in window and you may have to recreate players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `wn.clear()` removes all objects in window and you may have to recreate players. And this may need to assign keys to new objects.

I would also remove previous values from list `walls` because they may still exists on list (even if not displayed) and they can make some problems.

```
def setup_maze(level):
  global player
  global player2
  global walls

  player = Player()
  player2 = Player2()

  #Keyboard binding
  turtle.listen()
  turtle.onkey(player.go_left,"a")
  turtle.onkey(player.go_right,"d")
  turtle.onkey(player.go_up,"w")
  turtle.onkey(player.go_down,"s")
    
  #Keyboard binding
  turtle.listen()
  turtle.onkey(player2.go_left,"Left")
  turtle.onkey(player2.go_right,"Right")
  turtle.onkey(player2.go_up,"Up")
  turtle.onkey(player2.go_down,"Down")

  walls = []

  # ... rest ...
```